# Controller not processing Path Variable correctly - Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, path-variables, get-mapping

I have a list of customers who have some orders and I display them all in a table.
I have added a button in order to delete each order if desired.

This is the table of how I display them.

```
<table id="customers">
        <tr>
            <th>Customer</th>
            <th>Order</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
        <div th:each="customer : ${customers}">
          <tr>
            <td th:text="${customer.name}" style="font-weight: bold;"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr th:each="order : ${customer.orders}" >
            <td></td>
            <td th:text="${order.name}">
            <td>
                <a th:href="@{/manager/customer/{cid}(cid=${customer.id})/order/{oid}(oid=${order.id})}" class="button">Remove order</a>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </div>
</table>
```

In my Controller class I have the method where I process the deletion.

```
@GetMapping("/manager/customer/{cid}/order/{oid}")
    public String deleteCustomerOrder(@PathVariable(value="cid") Long cid, @PathVariable(value="oid") Long oid, Model model) {

        Customer c = customerService.findCustomerById(cid);
        //do stuff

        return "/manager/customerOrders";
    }
```

When I try to delete a specific order I get the following error

**Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Long'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "{cid}(cid=${customer.id})"**

The path looks like this:
**http://localhost:8080/manager/customer/%7Bcid%7D(cid=$%7Bcustomer.id%7D)/order/2**

Am I doing something wrong in the way that I get the IDs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All parameters should be defined together. Change href as follows:

```
<a th:href="@{/manager/customer/{cid}/order/{oid}(cid=${customer.id}, oid=${order.id})}" class="button">Remove order</a>
```

See section **Adding parameters** in [Thimeleaf documantation](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html) or in [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-thymeleaf-path-variables#multiple) tutorial